# Scrolling animation from fixed to normal?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I have an small animation here that works perfectly. The only thing I would like to have is that when the animation is finished it should scroll normally  again and dont be fixed anymore,  without changing its position. I have tried many things but nothing has worked.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
var arrow = document.getElementById('animatedArrow');
var line = document.getElementById('animatedLine');
var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

var linePosition = line.getBoundingClientRect();
var lineTop = linePosition.top;
var lineBottom = linePosition.bottom;

var arrowTop = Math.min(Math.max(scrollPosition - lineTop + 50, 50), 350);
arrow.style.top = arrowTop + 'px';

if (scrollPosition > lineBottom) {
    arrow.style.top = '350px';
}

if (scrollPosition > 100) { 
    line.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
} else {
    line.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
}
 });
```

```css
.content {
padding-top: 200px; /* Placeholder for the fixed space of the arrow */
}

.animated-line {
width: 2px;
height: 300px; /* Length of the line */
background-color: #ccc; /* Grey color for the line */
position: fixed;
top: 50px; /* Start position of the line */
left: 50%; /* Centering the line */
transform: translateX(-50%);
transition: background-color 0.5s ease; /* Transition effect for the line color */
 }

.animated-arrow {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;


border-top: 20px solid yellow; /* Yellow color for the arrow */
position: fixed;
left: 50%; /* Centering the arrow */
top: 50px; /* Start position of the arrow */
transform: translateX(-50%);
transition: top 1s ease; /* Transition effect for the arrow */
}
.k {padding: 1000px; }
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
    <div class="animated-line" id="animatedLine"></div>
    <div class="animated-arrow" id="animatedArrow"></div>  
</div>
```

I tried from fixed to static but then it went on the left side instead of staying in the middle.